# Java Jackson deserialize a special list

Tags: java, jackson

I try to solve deserialization problem, but now I'd like ask anyone to help me them.

I've a list from a classic Yaml:

```yaml
service:  
  env:
    - name: WAN_PORT
      value: "80"
    - name: LAN_PORT
      value: "8080"
    - name: SITE_URL
      value: "http://google.com"
```

I need those information for the following object:

```java
public class Env {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}
```

So far I created a simple ObjectMapper and use 'readValue' member of this object to process JsonNode.

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
jsonNode = jsonNode.get("service").get("env");
TypeReference<Map<String,Env>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
Map<String,Env> envMap = yamlFileMapper.getObjectMapper().readValue(jsonNode.toString(), typeRef);
```

I worked at past with Jackson and it's simpily worked as well with simple Object or List. Now I'd collection all env-pair to object and storing into Collection, like:

```java
List<Env> listOfEnv = ....
```

Thanks!

Comment: ` jsonNode = jsonNode.get("service").get("env");
            List<Env> envs = objectMapper.readValue(jsonNode.toString(), new TypeReference<List<Env>>() {
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested at the [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) github project page there is no need to create a new `TypeReference` for handling lists, you can directly use `List` inside the [`treeToValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#treeToValue-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode-java.lang.Class-) method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
JsonNode env = mapper.readTree(yaml).at("/service/env");
List<Env> list = mapper.treeToValue(env, List.class);
//ok, it prints [{name=WAN_PORT, value=80}, {name=LAN_PORT, value=8080}, {name=SITE_URL, value=http://google.com}]
System.out.println(list);
```